# Is there a way to sort the apps by usage frequncy?

Tags: ios, applications

I want to know if there's a quick way to find out the number of times one opens each app so that we can know which apps are really used by us frequently and we can sort them in that order.

I've tried to Google it but couldn't find any information that is really useful. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen any Spotlight metadata that counts the number an app is launched, you can, however, use the Date Last opened as a reference.

Open your /Applications folder and right click on the sort bar (where it says name, date modified, Size, etc.) and select Date Last Opened. Click on that to sort by that column and that's as close as you can get.

[image: lasopened]

If you're feeling fancy, you can create a smart folder that only shows the apps that you've opened in the last  number of days, weeks, etc. :)

Answer (score 2):

#### No, this isn't a native feature.

As of a default installation on iOS 6, this isn't possible. Like you mentioned, desktops in OSX can automatically re-arrange due to use, but iOS does not include any features along this line.

<sub>I would really enjoy this feature. You could always [recommend this to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/).</sub>

Comment: However, iOS does capture app invocation usage in the logs - so it's more a matter of collecting and parsing those logs on a computer - just like Apple might do if you submit those usage logs to them by opting in to data collection. I don't know if that data is actually transmitted in addition to crash logs, but they are stored in the same location by iTunes and iOS, so it's not such a far-fetched idea.

Comment: Good point. It wouldn't surprise me if there is a way to do either that or something similar with a jailbreak.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS multi-task bar (double tap on the home button to bring up) displays apps in the order they were last used.  Not a frequency sort, but a last-used sort, which may be closer than your icon arrangement to frequency-or-use, and thus possibly a quicker way to find an app you use frequently.

Answer (score 0):

A tool like [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) could be nice for your workflow and another tool like [Slife](http://code.google.com/p/slife/)

> Slife is an activity browser for the MacOS X. When the Slife client
>   runs, it observes as you interact with applications, documents and web
>   sites in your computer. It keeps track of when and for how long you
>   work on projects, read news, check email, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend that works at Apple, he is in charge of designing the iPhone cases.  I try not to annoy him on how to he should do his job and what suggestions I have,  but I once mentioned about arranging the icons based on frequency of use. He said that many people have sent them letters regarding this issue.  My response was well where the hell is the application, he said he didn't know.  End of story

Comment: This is kinda not an answer is it?