# Sorting iPhone/iPad Apps based on usage?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to sort the apps by usage frequncy?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54324/is-there-a-way-to-sort-the-apps-by-usage-frequncy)

Is there a way to have the Apps on my iPhone sorted based on usage frequency?  I found another thread, but it appeared to be focused on the MAC OS platform, not iOS.  In simple terms, I want the apps that I use all the time to be auto-sorted to the front.